# How to write a debugging helper for qtcreator?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, glm-math

When debugging my C++ program using the glm::vec3 class with gdb, the vector classes are quite cumbersome to work with:
[image: screenshot of the debugger within qtcreator]

I've read in the [manual](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html), that it's possible to write debug helpers.
I've managed to get qtcreator to load the file (the debugger exits immediately with an error, if my python file has a syntax error).

How can I write a minimalistic debugging helper?

#### What I've already tried:

Here's the C++ code

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class Foo
{
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  glm::vec3 vec3(42, 64, 256);
  Foo foo;

  (void)vec3;
  (void)foo;

  return 0;
}
```

This is my debugging helper:

```
from dumper import *

def qdump__glm__vec3(d, value):
    d.put("Yay, vec3 works :)")

def qdump__Foo(d, value):
    d.put("Yay, Foo works :)")
```

The vec3 code seems not to have any visible effect. For foo, it seems to do something, but instead of printing `Yay, Foo works :)` , qtcreator just shows `<not accessible>`. See the following screenshot:

[image: my progress so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2020**

As of glm 0.9.9.7 (2020), it seems that the typedef changed :

```cpp
typedef vec<3, float, defaultp>     vec3;
```

Therefore, the debug-helper should be updated to :

```py
from dumper import *

#debugging helper for    glm::(b|i|u|d)?vec[2-4]
def qdump__glm__vec(d, value):
    dim = value.type.templateArgument(0)
    
    d.putNumChild(dim)
    
    keys = ["x", "y", "z", "w"][0:dim]
    
    d.putValue("[" + ", ".join([str(value[key].value()) for key in keys]) + "]")

    if d.isExpanded(): 
        with Children(d):
            for key in keys:
                d.putSubItem(key, value[key])
```

This yields to the same result as before.

Answer (score 9):

## The short Answer: A Minimum example

Here's a minimum example for a debug helper:

C++ code:

```
class Foo
{
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  Foo foo;

  (void)foo;

  return 0;
}
```

The debug-helper:

```
from dumper import *

def qdump__Foo(d, value):
    d.putNumChild(0)
    d.putValue("Yay, Foo works :)")
```

The result:

[image]

### Explanation

You've mixed up `put` and `putValue`. To quote from the [link you've provided](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html):

> *put(self, value)* - Low level function to directly append to the output string. That is also the fastest way to append output.

`put` is a low level function and requires a very specific formating and thus may not be the optimal starting point for a minimum example.
Use instead `putValue`, this function can be used to print the value of a variable.

## The short Answer for glm::vec3

Here's the working example for glm::vec3:

C++ code:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
  glm::vec3 vec3(42, 64, 256);

  (void)vec3;

  return 0;
}
```

The debug-helper:

```
from dumper import *

def qdump__glm__tvec3(d, value):
    d.putValue("[{0}, {1}, {2}]".format(value["x"], value["y"], value["z"]))
    d.putNumChild(3)
    if d.isExpanded():
        with Children(d):
            d.putSubItem("x", value["x"])
            d.putSubItem("y", value["y"])
            d.putSubItem("z", value["z"])
```

The result:
[image: The final debugging view of a glm::vec3]

And to match your first screenshot for debugging a ray:
[image: Debugging a ray is now more fun ;)]

### Explanation

The reason, vec3 doesn't show up is, that `glm::vec3` is not the type, but just a typedef. glm::tvec3 is the type you are looking for:

```
typedef tvec3<float, highp>     highp_vec3;
// [...]
typedef highp_vec3          vec3;
```

So by replacing `def qdump__glm__vec3(d, value):` with `def qdump__glm__tvec3(d, value):`, gdb will be able to find your function.

To access the members themselves, for example the member `x`, use `value["x"]`. This way you can use `d.putValue` for a pleasing output.
For showing the members themselves in an expandable way, I've used the example from the [link you've provided](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html).

Comment: If you gain something like `Value(name='x',type=double,bsize=None,bpos=None,data=,address=0x1f59718)`, you might want to use `value['variable_name'].value()`