# QtCreator debug helpers "hello world"

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm trying to get started using [debug helpers in QtCreator](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html#debugging-helper-overview).

But I can't even get anything simple to work.

I made this simple python file:

```py
from dumper import *

def qdump_TestClass(d, value):
    d.putNumChild(0)
    d.putValue("hi")
```

Then add that file in here:

[image]

This is the C++ definition of the class:

```cpp
struct TestClass {
    int x, y;
};
```

I have been following the steps in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354573/how-to-write-a-debugging-helper-for-qtcreator). But that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double underscores in function name:

```
def qdump__TestClass(d, value):
         ^^
```

And, correct your path according to the documentation:

```
~/<Qt>/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/debugger/personaltypes.py
```

Use your Qt folder name (or path if it's not at `~`).

The path showing in that dialog box is relative to your `app`.

Here's a complete working example:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
struct TestClass
{
    int x {12}, y {34};
};

int main()
{
    TestClass t;
    (void) t;
    return 0;
}
```

**personaltypes.py**

```py
from dumper import *

def qdump__TestClass(d, value):
    d.putValue("TestClass")
    d.putNumChild(2)
    if d.isExpanded():
        with Children(d):
            d.putSubItem("x", value["x"])
            d.putSubItem("y", value["y"])
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean "realative to my app"? My Qt is installed in the "/opt/Qt" directory, is the path in the dialog box relative to that directory? Isn't it possible to have the file in my user directory?

Comment: @tuket: You're welcome! I meant that you need to use the standard Qt path to edit `personaltypes.py` file because the relevant Python files e.g. `dumper.py` are there. You can check your own installation path. I thought about a custom path but didn't test it yet. You might check that for yourself while you're on it e.g. by adding to `PATH`.

Comment: Yes, that was it, I needed to edit the `personaltypes.py` in the installation path. I'm not sure how to add the custom path, but I think I can work with this setup for now. Thank you!